# zeppelin-0.9.0-preview1 doesnt boot on few system

Tags: java, apache-zeppelin

On my local system zeppelin is working as expected
However on another system with same java version and ubuntu 16 I ran into below issue

```
Log dir doesn't exist, create /data/software/zeppelin-0.9.0-preview1-bin-all/logs
Pid dir doesn't exist, create /data/software/zeppelin-0.9.0-preview1-bin-all/run
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/data/software/apache-hive-2.3.7-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/data/software/zeppelin-0.9.0-preview1-bin-all/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2020-07-30T11:28:08,483 WARN [main] org.apache.zeppelin.conf.ZeppelinConfiguration - Failed to load configuration, proceeding with a default
2020-07-30T11:28:08,538 INFO [main] org.apache.zeppelin.conf.ZeppelinConfiguration - Server Host: 127.0.0.1
2020-07-30T11:28:08,538 INFO [main] org.apache.zeppelin.conf.ZeppelinConfiguration - Server Port: 8080
2020-07-30T11:28:08,538 INFO [main] org.apache.zeppelin.conf.ZeppelinConfiguration - Context Path: /
2020-07-30T11:28:08,538 INFO [main] org.apache.zeppelin.conf.ZeppelinConfiguration - Zeppelin Version: 0.9.0-preview1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.<init>(III)V
at org.apache.zeppelin.server.ZeppelinServer.setupJettyServer(ZeppelinServer.java:310)
at org.apache.zeppelin.server.ZeppelinServer.main(ZeppelinServer.java:132)
```

Here are logs from working system

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
```

I have downloaded standaone zeplin.. and No other config changes are done

Comment: can you try preview2? it was released today

Comment: sure.. DO you mind sharing download link? was not able to find on google

Comment: just standard Zeppelin download: https://zeppelin.apache.org/download.html

Comment: I am accessing it from India not able to see preview2 .. only preview 1 is availble

Comment: http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/zeppelin/zeppelin-0.9.0-preview2/zeppelin-0.9.0-preview2-bin-all.tgz

Comment: THanks a lot .. new version also same issue on particular machine.. Other machines it continues to work fine

Comment: I suggest to log JIRA at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN, or at least write to Zeppelin user list

Comment: As per doc zepplin 0.9 support JDK 8